# Insert Procedure check if foreign key exists in another table

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I am running into an issue where I am supposed to create a stored procedure. However my stored procedure needs to check if columns exists in a different table, this is my code at the moment:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE InsertTrail ( 
 @Mount             int,
 @Skill             varchar(20),
 @Snow              int,
 @Lift              int, 
 @Open              char(3),
 @AmountReal        int,
 @AmountFake        int,
 @Name              varchar(50)
  )
AS 
BEGIN 
If not exists (select mountainid from MOUNTAIN where @mount = mountainid) 
and
If not exists (select skilllevel from SKILLLEVEL where @skill = SkillLevel)
and 
If not exists (select snowmakerID from SNOWMAKER where @snow = SnowMakerID)
and
If not exists (select liftID from LIFT where @lift = LiftID)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TRAIL (MountainID, SkillLevel, SnowMakerID, LiftID, TOpen, AmountRealSnow, AmountFakeSnow, TrailName)
    values
    (@Mount, @Skill, @Snow, @Lift, @Open, @AmountReal, @AmountFake, @Name)
    Return @@Identity 
END
END
```

The columns I need to make sure exist are the mountainid in the mountain table, the skilllevel in the SKILLLEVEL table, the snowmakerid in the snowmakertable and the liftID in the lift table.

If you need any more information please let me know! Please help if you can!

Comment: Do you need to check if the **columns** exist, or do you need to check if there's any record with that **value** in those columns? Also, currently you're inserting your value only if none of these values exist.

Comment: I need to check if value I am inserting matches a record in the other table. So first i would need to change it from "If NOT EXISTS" to "IF EXISTS"

Comment: Hey Josh!!! Thanks so much for your help!! I was able to solve the issue by removing the "IF NOT" and left with it just "EXISTS" the procedure works successfully now!!! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. I still wrote an answere pointing out a few considerations/advice for this case.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You're performing a task by hand that the database system is already designed to enforce, if you've actually declared your foreign keys correctly. Why duplicate the work?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're inserting your value only if none of these values exist. If you want to check if all values exists before inserting you should use `IF EXISTS` instead of `IF NOT EXISTS`.

Still, I think the easiest way to achieve this is to make foreign keys and let the database administrator handle this validations.

I'm assuming `SQL SERVER` per your sample code's syntaxis. Correct me if I'm wrong to change the query:

```
ALTER TABLE TRAIL
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TRAIL_MOUNTAIN] FOREING KEY [MountainID]
REFERENCES [MOUNTAIN] ([MountainID])

ALTER TABLE TRAIL
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TRAIL_SKILLLEVEL] FOREING KEY [SkillLevel]
REFERENCES [SKILLLEVEL] ([SkillLevel])

ALTER TABLE TRAIL
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TRAIL_SNOWMAKER] FOREING KEY [SnowMakerID]
REFERENCES [SNOWMAKER] ([SnowMakerID])

ALTER TABLE TRAIL
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TRAIL_LIFT] FOREING KEY [LiftID]
REFERENCES [LIFT] ([LiftID])
```

Also IMO you should also check these values on client-side, and just let your SP "crash" when there's a non-referenced value.